# How to pass value of dropdown to instafeed tagName property

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, instafeedjs

I am using instafeedjs to show image based on tags. i want to add functionality to it so that it will show image based on the drop-down selection

```
<div class="instaTagsdd">
 <select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select> </div>
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VLpwoo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following jQuery snippet:

```
$('select').change(function() {
    feed.options.tagName = this.value;
    $('#' + feed.options.target).empty();
    feed.run();
});
```

See [Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rVyaVr)